Why is the middle pendant lamp in my dining room always swinging?
I recently installed three pendant lamps in my dining room. They're three large glass spheres, about 40 cm in diameter, arranged in a line on cables of equal length. I live on the 28th floor of an apartment building and I have neighbors above me (although I've never heard any noise from them).
The middle lamp - and the middle lamp only - is always swinging slightly. I keep my windows closed at all times and there's never any detectable air drafts. You can watch the phenomenon here.
What could be causing this?

If you can easily adjust the length (because they are chains and you can add/remove links), then modifying the swinging one may get it to stop.   Can't tell from your description if they are currently all (approximately) the same length

@BowlOfRed You're right, I had my physics very backwards. Changing the weight won't do anything.

If you make all three lamps swing, do you observe a different damping rate?

Your building is flexible, and tall, and is probably swaying slightly in the wind. For some reason, the middle lamp seems to couple with the sway of the building more than the others. It perhaps has a resonant frequency that matches that of the building more closely than the others. Or perhaps there is different damping between the lamps.

Well there is no factors other than a combination of building vibrations, resonance. It can be because maybe you cannot feel the footsteps of your neighbors ( the home above you) but the even small vibrations will swing this pendulum.
